# Getting an "ambiguous use of 'components' error" while running HKStatisticsCollectionQuery example code

Tags: swift, healthkit

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.current    
let interval = NSDateComponents()
interval.day = 7

// Set the anchor date to Monday at 3:00 a.m.
let anchorComponents = calendar.components([.Day, .Month, .Year, .Weekday], fromDate: NSDate())


let offset = (7 + anchorComponents.weekday - 2) % 7
anchorComponents.day -= offset
anchorComponents.hour = 3
```

I'm getting an Ambiguous use of 'components' error at anchor components declaration when I'm running the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  should  use  `Date`,  `DateComponents`  and  `Calendar`  instead of `NSDate`, `NSDateComponents` and `NSCalendar`. Then the old syntax needs to be updated to latest  `Swift` version.  Also you need to change constant(`let`) `interval` and `anchorComponents` to variable(`var`) as you are changing the values. Below is the fixed snippet,solution:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
var interval = DateComponents()
interval.day = 7


// Set the anchor date to Monday at 3:00 a.m.
var anchorComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year, .weekday], from: Date())


let offset = (7 + (anchorComponents.weekday ?? 0) - 2) % 7
anchorComponents.day = (anchorComponents.day ?? 0) - offset
anchorComponents.hour = 3
```